# "Access of undefined property" errors when the property is actually defined

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

**Answered my own question:** I can't declare any variables out in the open like that in my class. They have to be declared in a function, in this case, *initialize();*

I have a class called "Sushi"

```
package {

public class Sushi {
    private var cName: String; // This is the name of the sushi.
    private var cBio: String; // This is the description of the sushi.
    private var cWeight: Number; // This is the weight modifier of the sushi (please keep it between 0.1 and 2.0).
    //public var cSprite: MovieClip; // This is the sushi's graphic.
    private var cResist: Number; // This is the sushi's resistance modifier.

    public function setName(n:String): void {
        cName = n;
    }

    public function setBio(b:String): void {
        cBio = b;
    }

    public function setWeight(w:Number): void {
        cWeight = w;
    }

    public function setResist(r:Number): void {
        cResist = r;
    }

    public function getName(): String {
        return cName;
    }

    public function setCurrentChar(): void {
        MainClass.curChar = this;
    }

}
```

}

...and a main class. My main class creates two Sushi objects: test1 and test2.

```
private var test1 = new Sushi();
test1.setName("Test1");
private var test2 = new Sushi();
test2.setName("Test2");
```

Whenever I run it, I get the errors "Access of undefined property test1" and the same for test2. What am I doing wrong and how can I learn from my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Because you declared your members as `private`, they are not accessible outside the scope of the class.

In classes there are *access modifiers* which control scope.  For example:

- `internal` — visible to references inside the same package
- `private` — visible to references in the same class
- `protected` — visible to references in the same class and derived classes
- `public` — visible to references everywhere
- `static` — specifies that a property belongs to the class, as opposed to instances of the class

In your example `Sushi` class, because you declared those members as private they can only be seen by the `Sushi` class.

```
package {
    public class Sushi {
        private var cName:String;

        public function setName(n:String): void {
            cName = n;
        }
    }
}
```

However, you could declare the member as public:

```
package {
    public class Sushi {
        public var cName:String;
    }
}
```

When declared as public, you can now access them like:

```
var sushi:Sushi = new Sushi();
suschi.name = "Kappa Maki";
```

Your workaround is what's regarded as a property, in which a getter and setter are defined for a variable.

For example, here `_price` is property only the Sushi class has access to; however, it exposes two public methods to get or set the price value:

```
package {
    public class Sushi {
        private var _price:Number;

        public function get price():Number {
            return _price;
        }

        public function set price(value:Number):void {
            _price = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This object-oriented programming concept is known as encapsulation, and helps to hide internal complexities of your class.

By removing the setter, you can create a read-only property:

```
package {
    public class Sushi {
        private var _price:Number = 7.99;

        public function get price():Number {
            return _price;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can retrieve get the price; however, you cannot set it.

```
var sushi:Sushi = new Sushi();
trace("price is: $" + sushi.price); // traces: price is: $7.99
```

If you try to set the property, your compiler will throw an error:

```
var sushi:Sushi = new Sushi();
sushi.price = 1.99; // throws error: Property price is read-only.
```

Per their initialization, you can set their default value inline to their definition, as in:

```
package {
    public class Sushi {
        public var cName:String = "Kappa Maki";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set their initial values in the class constructor which is executed when you declare a `new` instance:

```
package {
    public class Sushi {
        public var cName:String;

        public function Sushi {
            cName = "Kappa Maki";
        }
    }
}
```